# Interest on the Savings account

Tags: riba

Salaam,

My question is about the interest the banks pay on the savings accounts that you maintain with them. The banks generally use your money lying in the account and invest it in the market, they make profit out of it and they only pass on a very small share of that Profit as an interest. Since Banks are sharing a small portion of the profit that they have made, is it still Haraam to use that money ? they can call it by some other name but they choose to call it as interest.